# Floating point precision rounding up or down

Tags: javascript

Due to conversion between binary and decimal numbers we often see precision errors in JS.

eg.: `137.80 * 100 = 13780.000000000002`

Although, is is technically possible that JS will return similar error but with negative precision?

eg.: `137.80 * 100 = 13779.999999999998`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I know how to deal with it. I'm trying to understand boundaries of the problem.

Comment: I wonder if using the binary IEEE-754 versions of these number might help clear things up?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. For instance, `0.3 / 10000` is `0.000029999999999999997` because `0.3` can't quite be represented, and the closest representation is just slightly lower that the actual value `0.3`. We can see that manifest in the output if we push the limits with the division.

Comment: Is this also possible with multiplication / addition ? I guess yes.

Comment: @shep4rd - I don't know, I haven't gotten that far into IEEE-754. I note that `0.3 * .0001` (the mathematical equivalent of the `0.3 / 10000` above) results in an output of `0.00003`. But I wouldn't take that as a guarantee of anything.